# Hidden Scroll on iframe

Tags: iframe, hidden

I used `iframe` on my Page. I want to hiding `iframe`'s scroll. I added `scrolling=no` in my code. But I can't see the entire of page, in this case.

How can I hiding scroll and I see entire of page?

Answer (score 0):

You can auto adjust the `iframe` to fit to content.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>

<IFRAME SRC="usagelogs/default.aspx" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>
```

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: this answer doesn't solve my problem. When I added your code in my page, scroll is shown. I add "scrolling=no" but I can't see entire of the page, again.